# How to make a width of "200 feet" in KML with a line?

Tags: kml

Assuming I have two latitude longitude points that make a Line, what is the proper "conversion" such that I can make it such that the line is stroked in a way that makes it a total of "200 feet" in width? (100 ft on both sides of the line)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#linestyle)

```
<gx:physicalWidth>
Physical width of the line, in meters.
```

Whether that is supported or not will depend on what tool you are using to render the KML.